# Regarding c# GUI ( If button clicked ) Certain labels will appear

Tags: c#

Currently using GUIfor my school project with these codes below。 I wanted to let certain labels / Textbox appear after I clicked button submit , how do i do it? thanks!

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SchoolProject
{
    public partial class Clothes : Form
    {
        public Clothes()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double Red1 = 13.00;
            double Blue1 = 12.00;
            double Green1 = 11.00;

            double Red2 = 6.00;
            double Blue2 = 7.00;
            double Green2 = 8.00;
            double total;


            if (rbnRed1.Checked && rbnRed2.Checked)
            {
                total = Red1 + Red2;
                MessageBox.Show("Red Tee & Red Crop Tee" + "Total:$ " + total.ToString("0.00"));
            }

            if (rbnRed1.Checked && rbnBlue2.Checked)
            {
                total = Red1 + Blue2;
                MessageBox.Show("Red Tee & Blue Crop Tee" + "Total: $" + total.ToString("0.00"));
            }

            if (rbnRed1.Checked && rbnGreen2.Checked)
            {
                total = Red1 + Green2;
                MessageBox.Show("Red Tee & Green Crop Tee" + "Total:$ " + total.ToString("0.00"));
            }
            //=======

            if (rbnBlue1.Checked && rbnRed2.Checked)
            {
                total = Blue1 + Blue2;
                MessageBox.Show("Blue Polo & Blue Crop Tee" + "Total:$ " + total.ToString("0.00"));
            }

            if (rbnBlue1.Checked && rbnBlue2.Checked)
            {
                total = Red1 + Blue2;
                MessageBox.Show("Red Polo Tee & Blue Crop Tee" + "Total: $" + total.ToString("0.00"));
            }

            if (rbnBlue1.Checked && rbnGreen2.Checked)
            {
                total = Red1 + Green2;
                MessageBox.Show("Red Polo Tee & Green Crop Tee" + "Total:$ " + total.ToString("0.00"));
            }
            //===========

            if (rbnGreen1.Checked && rbnRed2.Checked)
            {
                total = Red1 + Red2;
                MessageBox.Show("Red Polo Tee & Red Crop Tee" + "Total:$ " + total.ToString("0.00"));
            }

            if (rbnGreen1.Checked && rbnBlue2.Checked)
            {
                total = Red1 + Blue2;
                MessageBox.Show("Red Polo Tee & Blue Crop Tee" + "Total: $" + total.ToString("0.00"));
            }

            if (rbnGreen1.Checked && rbnGreen2.Checked)
            {
                total = Red1 + Green2;
                MessageBox.Show("Red Polo Tee & Green Crop Tee" + "Total:$ " + total.ToString("0.00"));
            }




        }

        private void groupBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let you have to show lable1 lable2 to show on click button1
so. you like this.
  on form load event add following code

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lable1.Visible = false;
        lable2.Visible = false;
    }
```

and in button1 click event

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lable1.Visible = true;
        lable2.Visible = true;
    }
```